# Removing Objects & Images from 600 page Adobe Acrobat X file - How?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

How do you remove Images & Objects from a 600 page Adobe Acrobat X file ? Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Adobe Photoshop can extract images from .PDF Files, and if all you need is a few then this manual process should be okay (assuming you own a copy of this software).  I have no idea if GIMP can do this.

Answer (score 5):

It was much easier in an earlier version of Acrobat Pro (using the Preflight tool). Here's how I managed to remove all images using the preflight tool of Acrobat XI:

1. Use Preflight tool to move images to separate layers
2. Set image layers to invisible (and disallow export, though I'm not sure if that had any influence)
3. Go to Tools, to the security menu on the right and use the option to remove all hidden elements
4. Save PDF

Answer (score 1):

I did this with Acrobat XI pro and Foxit phantom:
1.open file in acrobat XI, open Preflight with Ctrl+Shift+X
2.go to create PDF layers>create separate layers for...
3.after layers' been made, save the file
4.open the file in foxit phantom
5.notice which layer has those objects you want to remove, delete that layer.

also you can make layers invisible in Acrobat, but with Foxit you can delete a layer permanently!

Answer (score 0):

in acrobat 8 .. unfortunately i couldnt find the preflight action to move all images to a seperate layer ..

what i found -- on the left side you can enable the 'ribbon' "content" sidebar

in the content sidebar you can browse the document by page objects, which can then be directly selected and deleted

(the cursor edit "object tool" is way too clumsy if you want to delete a list of objects)

installed acrobat XI .. has as the aforementioned preflight option .. would be the better solution

Comment: To open preflight, press CTRL+SHIFT+X on windows.

Answer (score -1):

Use the PDF editing capabilities of `Adobe Acrobat`. You can manually select an individual object (using the "Edit Object tool") and remove it using <kbd>Del</kbd>.

You can also use the Preflight Tools to display a list of all text blocks and images in your file.

Comment: That needs 600 times of manual operation.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Adobe Acrobat Pro, go to *Pages* panel » *Watermarks* » *Remove Watermarks*.
Done.

Comment: This will only work if the image was added as a watermark, and no subsequent document flattening was performed.